# How to communicate with a biometric fingerprint reader in Django

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am working on a Django project that allows an administrator to register (signup) users. Users fingerprint is needed to be captured and saved into the database.

The issue I am having is how do I make a web browser communicate with a physical hardware, collect some data from the hardware (in this case fingerprint reader) and save it into Django database for future use.

I have a DigitalPersona USB fingerprint reader (I don't know if it may do the job).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general case, you need to write a plugins for browsers to capture fingerprint information and images to process on them.

For DigitalPersona Reader which you mentioned, there is such packages and SDKs which help you to reach the approach you want, you could find one here: [Python Web Biometric Authentication Software Module + Source Code for Developing and Integrating DigitalPersona Fingerprint Reader/Scanner With python Web Browser based Applications and Websites](https://jomutech.com/pythonwebbiometricsauthentication/)

But if you're looking for some other ways that plugin development is not required, you need some special fingerprint scanners like `CAMS ZK 7500` which has been developed in a special web-based infrastructure to provide such a solution you need!

for mentioned fingerprint scanner, you could find sample codes here:
[Javascript Based Fingerprint Reader for Website Login, Web based attendance and etc.](http://camsunit.com/application/javascript-based-fingerprint-scanner-for-website-authentication-and-attendance.html)